# Rails: Is there any way to load database information during initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some tables that are rarely changed.  Unfortunately, I need to call these tables quite often in controllers and that adds load time to certain pages.  For example, in one controller I have:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @groups = Group.all
        @events = Event.all
    end
end
```

It then occured to me that since groups and events rarely change, I could load these variables in initializers or as constants in a model so that they don't actually need to query the database in the moment.  I changed the above to the following:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    ALL = Group.all
end
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    ALL = Event.all
end

class PagesController
    def index
        @groups = Group::ALL
        @events = Event::ALL
   end
end
```

The above solution actually works in development.  In production on Heroku, however, it loads the variables in the controller.  I also tried setting up an initializer and defining `::Groups = Group.all` but this still loads the data when called in the controller.  Is there any way to load database info during initialization in a way that will work on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you didn't specify the tables' sizes.
If they have moderate sizes, I'd use the `Rails.cache` instead memoizing that fetches in controllers.

You can read more details here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#low-level-caching

By the way the data should be memoized as class variables not instance variables (also I would store `Foo.all.to_a` - so array instead of AR relation).

Though I don't recommend to do it anyway because I am not sure how often Heroku could reload the app.
Also it is for sure a hack and `Rails.cache` is indeed more preferable way to implement such caching. Furthermore, it provides a method to invalidate.